# Overloading << operator isn't working; still printing object address

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I'm trying to overload the stream operator `<<` but it is still just printing the object address instead of the object information like I have in the overload function definition. Here's my code, spent quite some time trying every example I could find on the web, but nothing is working. Please help alleviate some of my stress! Thanks.

Interval.h:

```
#ifndef INTERVAL_H
#define INTERVAL_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

class Interval {
    public:
        long start;
        long end;

        // Constructor
        Interval(long, long);

        // Deconstructor
        // Virtual to make sure that it calls the correct destructor
        virtual ~Interval();

        bool operator==(const Interval &other) const;
        bool operator!=(const Interval &other) const;
        bool operator<(const Interval &other) const;
        bool operator<=(const Interval &other) const;
        bool operator>(const Interval &other) const;
        bool operator>=(const Interval &other) const;
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Interval &i);

};
#endif
```

Interval.cpp:

```
#include "Interval.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Interval::Interval(long a, long b){
    // Assert that start is less than the end
    assert(a < b);
    start = a;
    end = b;
}

// Deconstructor
Interval::~Interval(){
}

bool Interval::operator==(const Interval &other) const{
    // Return true if both start and end are equal to other's
    if(start == other.start && end == other.end){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool Interval::operator!=(const Interval &other) const{
    // Return true(not equal) if either the start or end are different
    if(start != other.start || end != other.end){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
bool Interval::operator<=(const Interval &other) const{
    // Return true if the start is less than or equal other's start
    if(start <= other.start){
        return true;
    }
}

bool Interval::operator>(const Interval &other) const{
    // Return true if the end is greater than other's end
    if(end > other.end){
        return true;
    }
}

bool Interval::operator>=(const Interval &other) const{
    // Return true if the end is greater than or equal to other's end
    if(end >= other.end){
        return true;
    }
}


bool Interval::operator<(const Interval &other) const{
    // Return true if the start is less than other's
    if(start < other.start){
        return true;
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Interval &i){

    os << "Interval[" << i.start << ", " << i.end << "]" << endl;
    return os;
}

int main(void){
    Interval *test = new Interval(10,1000);
    cout << test << endl;
    cout << "test" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Interval*` is a pointer.  You are simply outputting the address.

Try dereferencing the pointer:

```
cout << *test << endl;
```

Or try this:

```
Interval test(10, 1000);   // not a pointer.
cout << test << endl;
```

Comment: i seriously can't believe i overlooked that. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Interval *test = new Interval(10,1000);
```

The syntax in C++ to create an object on the stack is

```
Interval test(10,1000);
```

Don't use pointers unless you have a good reason to do so.